# How to let different processes use different network interfaces Windows 7?

Tags: c++, c, windows, webrtc

I'm writing WebRTC related application. My system has multiple network interfaces. 
1. How can I let different processes use different network interfaces to communicate?
2. One Interface should be used for signaling and another will be for data transfer or video/audio call.?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`WSAIoctl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the [`SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code. That will allow you to get a list of network interfaces for your system, you will then be able to use the address of the interface you want in your `bind` calls.